# PHP ID not going through url

Tags: php, mysql

i cannot get a row to delete as the id is not going through the url. its a simple error somewhere and i cannot find the solution after having a look around for an hour.

this page contains the information on a table:

```
    <?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT review, ratings, date, user FROM reviews")
or die(mysql_error()); ;

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo 'There Arent Any Reviews Yet';
    } else {

echo "<table border='0'><table width=100% border='6'><tr><th>Comments/Thoughts</th><th>Ratings</th><th>Date</th><th>User</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['review']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['ratings']. " Stars</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['date']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $info['user']. "</td>";

        echo "<td>" . " <a href='deletereview.php?review_id=" . $info['review_id'] . "'>Delete</a> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

it goes to deletereview.php which carries out the delete function:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once '../includes/db.php';  
$id = $_GET['review_id'];

$info = "DELETE FROM reviews WHERE review_id = '$id'";

mysql_query($info) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
echo "<h2>Review Deleted</h2>";

?>
```

any ideas guys?

Comment: `1';DROP TABLE reviews;--`

Comment: @webarto is correct - A simple string like `1' OR '1' = '1` will result in deleting your entire reviews table, as it is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Destructive actions shouldn't be triggered by a GET request. It's too easy to bookmark or reissue a GET request by simply using browser history, resulting in potential unintentional deletes.  Ideally, you'd issue a DELETE (via AJAX) request rather than a GET to trigger a delete.  A POST request (e.g. form or AJAX POST) would be an acceptable alternative.  Make sure you verify the type of request on the server and forbid GET requests for your deletion scripts.

Comment: The sample code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html), which is a very serious [security risk](http://bobby-tables.com/). To fix this hole, switch from the outdated mysql extension to [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/PDO.prepared-statements), passing values as parameters to the statement rather than interpolating them directly into the string. If you need a PDO tutorial, try ["Writing MySQL Scripts with PHP and PDO"](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html). The site you save may just be your own.

Answer (score 7):

You're not selecting the review_id in the query, so $info["review_id"] is always null.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the other answers, I'll say this:

Your database *will* get jacked if you do not sanitize your variables.

For instance, what happens if I pass `review_id=' OR '1'='1`?

```
DELETE FROM reviews WHERE review_id = '' OR '1'='1'
```

This query will delete everything in `reviews`.

[`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables before using them in your MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to select the **review_id**.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT review_id, review, ratings, date, user FROM reviews")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not selecting `review_id` from the database but you use `$info['review_id']` to set the ID on the URL. Just change your first line to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT review_id, review, ratings, date, user FROM reviews")
```

Also you *must* escape the input with `mysql_real_escape_string`:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['review_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the review_id in the query. But also you have to check for some SQL injection, because with the GET request it's easy to delete all the table records.